# Async / Sequentials promises, detect the end

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have an array of promises ( Q ) functions:

```
var tasks = [p, p, p, p, ...];
```

I want to be able to execute them asynchronously or synchronously and detect when all the promises have been executed. I'am able to make it work synchronously :

**1) synchronously**

```
tasks.reduce(function(prev,cur){
    return prev.then(cur);
}, Q.resolve()).then(function() {
   console.log("finished")
});
```

**2) asynchronously**

```
var result = Q();
tasks.forEach(function (f) {
   return result.then(f);
});
```

However, how to detect when all promises have been executed when working asynchronously ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The example is taken from [Q doc](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences)

Comment: Is tasks a standard Javascript array?

Comment: Better headings would be (1) In Series, and (2) In Parallel. Both involve asynchronism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `forEach`, but rather `map` to get an array of promises from your array of functions. With that, you can use [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) to get a promise for all the results (when all the promises have been resolved):

```
Q.all(tasks.map(function(f) {
   return f();
})).then(function() {
   console.log("finished")
});
```